# KTor URLBuilder encodedPath with dynamic path

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build a network module for Multiplatform project with `ktor`.
My code for `GET` request is something like this:

```
val result = httpClient.get<HttpResponse> {
                    url {
                        protocol = baseProtocol
                        host = baseUrl
                        encodedPath = urlPath

                    }
}
```

In some point my path contain a user id like this `/users/{user_id}`.
I can do a search and replace in string and replace this `user_id` with actual value, BUT is there any other way to do this? any `ktor` specific way.

For example with `Retrofit` we have this:

```
@GET("users/{user_id}/")
SomeData getUserData(@Path("user_id") String userId);
```

EDIT: adding more code

```
val result = httpClient.get<HttpResponse> {
                    url {
                        protocol = baseProtocol
                        host = baseUrl

                        var requestPath = request.requestPath.value
                        request.path?.forEach {
                            requestPath = requestPath.replace(it.first, it.second)
                        }
                        encodedPath = requestPath

                        if (request.parameters != null) {
                            parameters.appendAll(getParametersFromList(request.parameters))
                        }
                    }
```

the `request.path?.forEach { requestPath = requestPath.replace(it.first, it.second)}` replacing any runtime path value.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Are you trying to refactor the logic around building the `urlPath` string?

Comment: @CraigOtis No, I'm just trying to put the value of `user_id` into the encodedPath in runtime.

Comment: Are you possibly looking for path variables? https://ktor.io/servers/features/routing.html#path

Comment: @CraigOtis exactly, but for client, your link is for server, how can I use it in client?

Comment: It sounds like you want a method `getUserData(userId)` that builds the URL given the User ID as a method argument. What does the code _around_ your `httpClient.get` call look like right now?

Comment: @CraigOtis please look at the update in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188999/discussion-between-craig-otis-and-mehdok).

Comment: Have you found a solution?